# How to change model and update database, make migrations, in flask-admin?

Tags: python, flask-admin

I already have my flask-admin app with its models and database and tables created..

Now I would like to add a field to model and that should be reflected in the database by a new column in the model's corresponding table.

With django one would create then apply migrations..

How do I make migrations/schema-changes in flask-admin?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking out the [section](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) on SQLAlchemy-based database migrations in  Miguel Grinberg's Database Flask Mega-Tutorial. He uses low-level SQLAlchemy APIs to put the database under version control and automate the process of database version upgrades or downgrades.

Alternatively, I recommend using Miguel Grinberg's [Flask-Migrate](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate) extension which implements the functionality he describes in the aforementioned tutorial. Using this extension, you simply add an instance of the `Migrate` object to your application, then perform database migrations using a command line interface provided by the extension.

Comment: surprised its not a straight foward documented task to add a collumn